# How can I best explain a tuple to an audience?

Tags: c++, tuples

I've been tasked with explaining a small segment of code to a class, and was wondering if any of my points are incorrect, or inaccurate. The code segment is as follows:

```
std::tuple<int, float, char> ifc(3, 4.5f, 'c');
std::cout << std::get<0>(ifc);
std::cout << std::get<1>(ifc);
```

And the key points I've written about the code are:

- Tuples are objects that can hold lots of different types, and can contain any number of elements inside them.
- Get function returns the value at the given index of the tuple, much like an array
- The tuple is defined at compile time, therefore it uses static memory allocation. This means memory is allocated for the tuple when the program is run and it persists until the program exits.
- The tuple is pushed to the stack at run time, during memory allocation. When the std::get functions are called, it goes to the stack at the relevant index address and returns the type and value stored there.

I would also like to expand on the final point, as I am quite unsure of how memory allocation works for tuples.

Any input would be greatly appreciated! :)
Thanks

Comment: Tell them it's like a structure where all data members are anonymous, and can can/should be only accessed by their ordinal position within the struct. Which it kind of is.

Comment: If you are willing to dirty your hands with detail a little, there is a tutorial with a walkthrough of creating a tuple template [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/). It may help you understand the memory allocation specifics.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, What's your reasoning behind the "should" part? It is certainly *possible* (in the current standard) to use `std::get<type>(ifc)`, which will give a compiler error if ambiguous.

Comment: "It's like a pair but more flexible"?

Comment: So would I be safe to say that the tuple in my example uses static memory allocation? Thanks for all your help guys, and @PaulRooney I'm reviewing that source as we speak. Thanks for that :)

Comment: First wrote "should", then realized there's no other option :)

Comment: _"The tuple is defined at compile time, therefore it uses static memory allocation"_ o.O

Comment: If you're teaching a class, you would be doing them all a favour by avoiding these wonky implementation details entirely. Teach them about the language's abstractions, instead; that'll be far more valuable.

Answer (score 2):

A tuple is a mathematical concept, which is a finite *ordered list of elements*.

But a `std::tuple` is not an object, a `std::tuple` is a type, actually a templated type, which allows to create a specific types with specific ordered list of elements as types. You can see it as a way to define a `struct` with anonymous fields, where instead that referring to them by name, you do by index (that's why a tuple must be ordered).

Memory allocation for an `std::tuple` will mostly work exactly as an equivalent `struct`. If the instance is on stack then accessing the field is equivalent to getting the address of the tuple and add the offset of the field to it (which is known at compile time). Which would be sort of:

```
struct Tuple {
  int a;
  char b;
  double c;
};

Tuple t = Tuple{1,'a',1.0};
assert(&t.c == &t + offsetof(Tuple, c));
```

Comment: `&t + offsetof(Tuple, c)` should be `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t) + offsetof(Tuple, c)`. Not sure what you want to express by the `assert` btw.